# How to make JScrollPane set to the bottom when a JButton is pressed?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a panel in which there is a `JScrollPane` and a `JButton`. I want to know how I can set the scroll pane's vertical scroll bar to bottom when I press the button.

I have tried code:-

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    writeClient();
    jScrollPane2.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(jScrollPane2.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum());
}
```

But it doesn't lead to extreme bottom - a little space is still left at the bottom.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

I am having problems to reproduce you issue. If you can post all the relevant code (and maybe include a screenshot), we can give you better advice. When I run the code below, pressing the button moves the scroll pane all the way down:

```
public class ScrollPaneBottom {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new ScrollPaneBottom().test();
    }

    private void test() {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Move a scroll pane to the bottom");
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 110);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    final String[][] data = {{"One", "Hello"}, {"Une", "Bonjour"}, 
        {"Ein", "Hallo"}, {"Uno", "Hola"}, {"Een", "Hallo"}};
    final String[] columnNames = {"Number", "Word"};
    final JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames));
    final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        final JButton button = new JButton("Move to the bottom");
        button.addActionListener(e -> {
            final int maximum = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum();
            scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(maximum);
        });
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```